# Wish to learn a new programming language

Tags: programming-languages

I wish to learn a new programming language but there are so many out there! So thought I'd ask here if there are any that correspond with what I wrote in this list that you might know of:

- Making applications with GUI
- That would preferably run on any system, preferably Windows (I run Windows 7)
- That would not need a hardcore IDE and hopefully no compiling
- That is not incredibly advanced (Hard syntax paired with OOP etc.)
- That does not need any 'platform' or 'component' installed to work (can be opened with a click, say an .exe file or any other file type)

I already know:

- HTML, JavaScript and PHP

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: There's a trick to learning.  It's called "search".  Your question has already been asked here.  Use the search box and find related questions.  Read those.  Then update your question if  it is actually unique.

Comment: You should list which languages you already know.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend Python to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some mutually exclusive options here.

For example, no compiling and opening an .exe.  An exe file is generated via compilation.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com) probably best suits your needs.  It runs on just about everything, doesn't need an IDE (though qtcreator is a fantastic one, I suggest trying it before you choose not to use an IDE) and is easy to learn and well documented.

If you want compile-less then you'll need to use the python or other scripting language bindings too it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest C-sharp / F-sharp combination with WPF thrown into that to get GUI's going...
It a pretty rough learning curve but the combinations are endless...

A couple things to certainly look into:

- PRISM
- M-V-VM ( Model , View, Viewmodel)

If you are interested in an other back-end persistancy try going into object databases, such a great new world opened up for me when I discovered all the things you can do with that... ( DB4O is my preferred one at this moment.. it has loads of info and a very active community )

It is only limited by your imagination ;)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend HTML5+Javascript.

- You can use Canvas or SVG for
  graphic.
- It works depending on the browser. So
  any OS or system can use it.
- Javascript and HTML can be edited in
  any thing for example: notepad.
- You can write your JS using OOP.
- How to open a HTML file? just
  double-click on it.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those questions of having 10000 people going to an Ice cream shop and then choosing which flavour they want. So far I have worked with Delphi and C#, I am doing SQL, Asp.net and javascript, well, basically!

The answer should be somewhat simple. Go check out which programming language fits your needs, and is in great demand in the working world. If you want to program websites for companies, then PHP, ASP.NET and the older HTML is for you. As far as I know, flash is also coding.#

Another way to look at this question is not only the availability of the language you seek, but its future, if it will become obsolete or the coding language of the century.All coding is the same, but some are more rigorous in certain tasks (like C# and delphi are good languages to build forms applications to handle tasks for data manipulation, integration and whatnot.)

The answer to this question is to explore! What is *Your* flavour?  Sitting in front of a desk doing CRUD operations and staring into a gui which has countless buttons and textb
oxes, but real in-depth code, or to start into a rich gui with XML based code?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but HTML is still reliable :D